# RabbitMQ fails to consume messages after reopening publishing channel

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I'm trying to consume messages which were published in the same process and can't understand why messages don't consume if publishing channel is reopened.

For example, the following code works fine:

http://pastie.org/10064946

And the following does not:

http://pastie.org/10064957

The only difference is that in second sample the new channel is created for each publish

Comment: only thing I see is that you are declaring exclusive, auto_delete queues that are tied to the channel. Might it be that on the second example those channels are gone and therefore the queues get deleted?

Comment: @old_sound I've tried publishing from another process and it works fine.